# Android Sql Like

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite for my database and what I need is get the list of the username based on a specific string

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM username_table WHERE username like 'john[^0-9]%'
```

Results are:

```
john1, johnny12, john123, johnatan12 ... (Except john I dont know why)
```

What i need is only john or john with any number besides him

Expected Result

```
john, john012, john1245, john1, john46...
```

Thank you

Comment: Using `like 'john'` will return `Johnatan` too

Comment: @Hector yep I only need John with with/wothout numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [REGEXP](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) operator? Following query works like a charm for data you've provided:

```
SELECT * FROM username_table WHERE (username REGEXP 'john[0-9]*');
```

Please note, it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM username_table WHERE username like 'john?[0-9]℅'
```

Comment: it still the same it renders johnny01, johnatan12 etc

Comment: 0 Rows returned from: SELECT * FROM username_table WHERE username like 'john?[0-9]℅'

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  SELECT * FROM username_table WHERE username like 'john[^0-9]%' or username like 'john';
```

Comment: @harpun "Not an answer" is for answers that aren't even *attempts* at answering the question.

Comment: what is the problem with my answer @immibis

Comment: @sabsab Nothing, another user flagged it as not an answer though.